# What is the best way to store DateTime in SQL Server to provide maximum search speed at large table?

Tags: sql-server, search, datetime, indexing

What is the best way to store `DateTime` in SQL Server to provide maximum search speed for large table? The table contains the records, and one row has to contain the date and time.

The searches are like

```
Value > '2008-1-1' AND Value < '2009-1-1'
```

or

```
Value > '2008-1-1' AND Value < '2008-31-1'
```

etc.

Which is the best? The `DateTime` with index? The unixstamp in `long` with index? Multiple `int` fields like year, month, day ect.? Or something else?

Comment: Store it as [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). Actually i don't understand the question.

Comment: Could it be slow to make sql iterate over thousands (may be millions) records in the table with that sort of queries?

Comment: Do you **always** have the lower bound at the same date ('2008-1-1')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the smallest datatype that supports what level of datetime accuracy you need. 
e.g.

- datetime2 if you need high accuracy down to 100 nanoseconds (6-8 bytes) (SQL 2008+)
- datetime for accuracy to 3.33ms (8 bytes)
- smalldatetime for accuracy to the minute (4 bytes)
- date for accuracy to the day (no time stored, 3 bytes) (SQL 2008+)

You don't mention how large a table you are talking. But there are strategies for dealing with improving query performance on top of standard indexing strategy (e.g. partitioning, filtered indices)

Comment: He has mentioned it in a comment: "over thousands (may be millions)"

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yep, saw that comment appeared after I answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows only date and no time element.
If you only need date then use the relatively new DATE type instead of DATETIME.
It is smaller and with an index should be fast.

Comment: [Index Creation Guidelines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/indexcreationguidelines/1389/): "In most cases an index for datetime column is not required (and may be a bad idea as well). So do not create it until you know and test your query. If the search will use a datetime function in ‘where’ clause or some conversion mechanism, most likely the index will not be used by the Query Optimizer but performance will suffer. "

Answer (score 0):

If you choose smaller data type, you can store more records on a single page, so there will be less IO operations, so it will work faster.

Of cource, introducing indexes may improve performance. Indexes should include as little columns as possible, to store maximum ammount of records on a single page.

But...

Premature optimization is root all of evil

For the first you should store date as date, considering precision you need. If later you face some performance issues, you have to investigate which queries have performance issues and may be introduce some indexes, but you have to make sure those indexes cover you queries.